# При открытом 2-м окне появляется ошибка при нажатии любой кнопки в 1-м окне

Tags: python, ооп, классы, pyqt, qt-designer

С помощью *Qt Designer* создал два окна, 
main (окно 1) **`window_8_t.py`** с классом `Ui_MainWindow` и 
help (окно 2) **`help_window_dialog_t.py`** с классом `Ui_Help_w`.

В окне 1 есть кнопка, при нажатии на которую появляется окно 2 (Help). И если, при открытом окне 2, нажать на любую кнопку в 1-м окне появляется ошибка, даже после закрытия окна 2 невозможно оперировать окном 1:

> AttributeError: 'Ui_Help_w' object has no attribute 'textEdit'

тут `textEdit` элемент окна 1 который вызвался случайной кнопкой.
Как сделать так что бы при открытом окне 2, можно было оперировать окном 1?

**main.py**:

```
import sys
import numpy as np
import window_8_t
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QWidget
from PyQt5.uic import loadUi
from window_8_t import Ui_MainWindow
from help_window_dialog_t import Ui_Help_w
import random

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow, Ui_Help_w):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.ui = window_8_t.Ui_MainWindow()
        self.ui.setupUi(self) 
        self.ui.pushButton_help.clicked.connect(self.open_window)  
        self.ui.pushButton_print.clicked.connect(self.print_out)

    def open_window(self):
        self.window = QMainWindow()
        self.ui=Ui_Help_w()
        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
        self.window.show()

    def print_out(self):
        self.ui.textEdit.clear()
        n=random.randint(0,9)
        self.ui.textEdit.append("SOME TEXT")
        self.ui.textEdit.append(str(n))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

py файл ui окна 2 `help_window_dialog_t.py`:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_Help_w(object):
    def setupUi(self, Help_w):
        Help_w.setObjectName("Help_w")
        Help_w.resize(446, 123)
        self.textEdit_help = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(Help_w)
        self.textEdit_help.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 30, 371, 81))
        self.textEdit_help.setReadOnly(True)
        self.textEdit_help.setObjectName("textEdit_help")

        self.retranslateUi(Help_w)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Help_w)

    def retranslateUi(self, Help_w):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Help_w.setWindowTitle(_translate("Help_w", "Help"))
        self.textEdit_help.setHtml(_translate("Help_w", "<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC \"-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0//EN\" \"http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/strict.dtd\">\n"
"<html><head><meta name=\"qrichtext\" content=\"1\" /><style type=\"text/css\">\n"
"p, li { white-space: pre-wrap; }\n"
"</style></head><body style=\" font-family:\'MS Shell Dlg 2\'; font-size:7.8pt; font-weight:400; font-style:normal;\">\n"
"<p align=\"justify\" style=\" margin-top:12px; margin-bottom:12px; margin-left:0px; margin-right:0px; -qt-block-indent:0; text-indent:0px;\">SOME TEXT2</p></body></html>"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    Help_w = QtWidgets.QDialog()
    ui = Ui_Help_w()
    ui.setupUi(Help_w)
    Help_w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

**`window_8_t.py`**:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(394, 256)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton_print = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_print.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(220, 10, 151, 91))
        self.pushButton_print.setObjectName("pushButton_print")
        self.textEdit = QtWidgets.QTextEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.textEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 10, 201, 87))
        self.textEdit.setObjectName("textEdit")
        self.pushButton_help = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_help.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 140, 241, 91))
        self.pushButton_help.setObjectName("pushButton_help")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton_print.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "PRINT"))
        self.pushButton_help.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Help"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Все файлы лежат в одной папке, `.ui` файлы конвертированы в `.py`.

Comment: опубликуйте модуль `window_8.py`

Comment: пожалуйста, предоставьте [mcve], который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: добавил воспроизводимый пример

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я отметил для вас какие изменения надо сделать. Если что-то не понятно - спросите.

**main.py**

```
import sys
# ???import numpy as np
import random

from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
# ???from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

# ???import window_8_t
from window_8_t import Ui_MainWindow
from help_window_dialog_t import Ui_Help_w


# +++ vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
class HelpWindowDialog(QtWidgets.QDialog, Ui_Help_w):
    def __init__(self, parent = None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
# +++ ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^


class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):                # ???, Ui_Help_w):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Window, self).__init__(parent)
#        self.ui = window_8_t.Ui_MainWindow()

        self.setupUi(self) 
        
        self.pushButton_help.clicked.connect(self.open_window)  
        self.pushButton_print.clicked.connect(self.print_out)

    def open_window(self):
# ???        self.window = QMainWindow()
#        self.ui=Ui_Help_w()
#        self.ui.setupUi(self.window)
# ???        self.window.show()

        self.window = HelpWindowDialog()
        self.window.show()

    def print_out(self):
        self.textEdit.clear()
        n = random.randint(0, 9)
        self.textEdit.append("SOME TEXT")
        self.textEdit.append(str(n))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @John_2202 что не так?

Comment: тоесть, даже если окно будет содержать только текст (добавленый в qt designer) без всяких операций, то все равно нужно создавать клас? не знал, точнее не думал что нужно, спасибо

Comment: @John_2202 пожалуйста.